# JSON incorrect escaping Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem of JSON encoding on my rails application:

```
h = {:status=>200, :promotions=>[{:id=>719788, :title=>"test"}]}
```

and result of

```
puts h.to_json
```

is

```
{"status":200,"promotions":{"{\"id\"=>719788, \"title\"=>\"test\"}":null}}
```

Which is not the expected result!

This is the correct result:

```
{"promotions":[{"title":"test","id":719788}],"status":200}
```

What could generate such error in JSON generation?

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v
Rails 3.1.4
gem list ==> json (1.6.6, 1.5.4)
```

Comment: That's odd. Is this the exact code you're using in your app?

Comment: these are the results of commands in rails console. This is odd indeed, because it was working before and I guess someone updated something somewhere... but I can't find what exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this has nothing to do with a configuration of rails or ruby...
One of the engineer added this into core_extensions for Array

```
def to_hash # Recursively convert array to hash 
 inject({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
   value = value.to_hash if value.kind_of?(Array)
   hash.merge!({key => value})
 end
end
```

I guess I can delete this question tomorrow